# Scrapy : not able to schedule

Tags: python, scrapy, scheduled-tasks

I want to run a spider every couple of minutes.  I put the following  script  in my project that I want to call for this purpose.

```py
import schedule, os
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings

def job():
      process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
      process.crawl('amazon_spider')
      process.start() # error: twisted.internet.error.ReactorNotRestartable 
      #process.start(stop_after_crawl=False)  #process get stuck

while True:
     schedule.run_pending()
     schedule.every().minutes.do(job)
```

With this appoach the process get the following error:

***twisted.internet.error.ReactorNotRestartable***   or stuck if I  put  ***process.start(stop_after_crawl=False)***

From a previous  stackoverflow posted  I  also try this :

```py
from twisted.internet import reactor
from amazon.spiders.amazon_spider import AmazonSpider
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner

def run_crawl():

    runner = CrawlerRunner({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)',
    })
     deferred = runner.crawl(AmazonSpider)
     deferred.addCallback(reactor.callLater, 10, run_crawl)

     return deferred

     run_crawl()
     reactor.run()
```

The  process get stuck again in the middle of the parse function . I really don't know what to try next .  If you have an idea please let me know. Thank you in advance ....  ( By the way , it is not a duplicate , since the posts on the same subject didn#t solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I use apscheduler

```
pip install apscheduler
```

then

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from apscheduler.schedulers.twisted import TwistedScheduler

from Demo.spiders.baidu import YourSpider

process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
scheduler = TwistedScheduler()
scheduler.add_job(process.crawl, 'interval', args=[YourSpider], seconds=10)
scheduler.start()
process.start(False)
```

Comment: Spiders do open but are not crawling. No errors but no items either.